# How to store a Dictionary<string,object> inside a Container in Windows 8 Metro app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, storage, containers

I am a windows Phone developer.. I recently started development for windows 8 metro style apps. Am trying to figure out the basics like storing user data. I tried storing a dictionary of type dictionary inside a container. When i try to do this i get an exception saying data of this type cannot be stored! What am i doing wrong? my code looks something like this:

this is my storage manager class:

```
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

public bool SaveToStorage(string containerName, string key, object dataToStore)
{
    try
    {
        if (!localSettings.Containers.ContainsKey(containerName))
        {
            localSettings.CreateContainer(containerName, ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
        }
        localSettings.Containers[containerName].Values.Add(key, dataToStore);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is how am passing the dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, object> profileDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
profileDict.Add(Utilities.FirstName, txtBoxFName.Text);
profileDict.Add(Utilities.LastName, txtBoxLName.Text);
profileDict.Add(Utilities.EMail, txtBoxEmail.Text);
SaveToStorage(Utilities.MyMedicalProfileContainer, Utilities.MyProfile, profileDict);
```

Can someone please help me out with this.. What am i doing wrong?? 
Any help and suggestions appreciated!

Why isn't isolated storage dll available to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XML serialization. `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` doesn't support all the data types. There are also some libs available which provide feature similar to isolated storage. They also use XML serialization.

[Generic Object Storage Helper for WinRT](https://winrtstoragehelper.codeplex.com/)

[Windows 8 Isolated Storage](https://isolatedstoragew8.codeplex.com/)